# « Déjeuner à la fourchette » : précisions ?

Tags: sens, locutions, alimentation, origine-ou-raison

La locution *déjeuner à la [fourchette](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fourchette)*, signifiant « prendre de la viande ou des mets solides au petit déjeuner » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fourchette) dit « déjeuner » tout court dans une liste de dérivés, aussi ailleurs sur le Web, d'où un doute dans mon esprit), est *vieillie* (TLFi, avec un ex. à dix heures.). Au *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sous la dir. d'A. Rey, ed. Le Robert, à *déjeuner*), on dit entre autres que le « syntagme *petit-déjeuner* (in Larousse, 1866) qui s'oppose initialement à *déjeuner à la fourchette* (1846), ou à *second déjeuner*, *grand déjeuner*, sortis d'usage, a pris la place de déjeuner au sens ancien de « repas du matin », quand déjeuner à remplacé dîner pour « repas de midi » [...] ». Je lis l'article au sujet du restaurant [*Café Anglais*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caf%C3%A9_Anglais) (1802-1913) sur Wikipédia, auquel on réfère dans le [*Festin de babette*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Festin_de_Babette) (d'après l'oeuvre de [Karen Blixen](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Blixen)), et on dit qu' :

> On y déjeunait « à la fourchette », on y mangeait à la carte, on y
>   commandait les meilleurs vins de Bordeaux et de Bourgogne et l'« eau
>   divine », de Saint-Pierre-sur-Dives ; on y dégustait le potage à la
>   Cameroni.
>
> [ *Wikipédia*, à *Café Anglais* ]

---

Peut-on confirmer le sens de l'expression, expliquer pourquoi c'est disparu, et indiquer à quoi on référerait dans l'article au juste ?

- Peut-on confirmer que c'est bien d'un *petit déjeuner* dont on parle
  dans la locution *déjeuner à la fourchette* ?
- Comment le syntagme *petit-déjeuner* s'opposerait-il à *déjeuner à la
  fourchette, second déjeuner, grand déjeuner* (DHLF) ?
- À quoi réfère-t-on dans l'article (Wikipédia) quand on l'emploie, les guillemets sont-ils usuels et y changent-ils quelque chose ?
- Si c'est vieilli ou sorti d'usage, a-t-on une autre locution pour «
  prendre de la viande ou des mets solides au petit déjeuner », ou le
  fait que ce soit vieilli est-il simplement tributaire du remaniement au lexique
  pour les repas au milieu du 19<sup>e</sup> ; a-t-on déjà parlé de
  *petit-déjeuner à la fourchette* ?

Comment: Note subsidiaire : petit déjeuner ne prend pas de trait d'union quand c'est un nom. Avec un trait d'union, c'est un verbe, un néologisme (assez déplaisant à mon avis) pour dire "prendre le petit déjeuner" : je petit-déjeune, tu petit-déjeunes, etc.

Comment: @Steph Merci, en effet. J'ai revisé pour plus de cohérence. La citation au DHLF utilise le trait d'union dans sa phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Peut-on confirmer que c'est bien d'un petit déjeuner dont on parle dans la locution déjeuner à la fourchette ?

Pas vraiment, c'est un petit déjeuner qui s'est décalé en fin de matinée. Aujourd'hui, on dirait un *brunch*...

> Comment le syntagme petit-déjeuner s'opposerait-il à déjeuner à la fourchette, second déjeuner, grand déjeuner (DHLF) ?

Le petit déjeuner se prend au lever, le déjeuner à la fourchette/second déjeuner/grand déjeuner se prenait en fin de matinée mais ne concernait que les classes aisées. La fourchette impliquait un repas comportant de la viande, et s'opposait aux repas que l'on aurait pu appeler « à la cuillère », à base de soupe.

> À quoi réfère-t-on dans l'article (Wikipédia) quand on l'emploie, les guillemets sont-ils usuels et y changent-ils quelque chose ?

Il s'agit du repas de midi. Les guillemets sont là pour monter qu'il s'agit d'une expression figée (mais oubliée).

> Si c'est vieilli ou sorti d'usage, a-t-on une autre locution pour « prendre de la viande ou des mets solides au petit déjeuner », ou le fait que ce soit vieilli est-il simplement tributaire du remaniement au lexique pour les repas au milieu du 19e ; a-t-on déjà parlé de petit-déjeuner à la fourchette ?

Il ne faut pas trop essayer de calquer notre modèle de repas actuel assez figé  (un repas le matin, un à midi et un le soir) à la société du XVIII<sup>e</sup> et du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Il y avait alors une beaucoup plus grande diversité dans les heures auxquelles était pris les repas et dans le nombre même de repas pris : un, deux, trois ou quatre, suivant les groupes sociaux, les métiers et les moyens des personnes. Il ne s'agit pas non plus de prendre de la viande au repas matinal, ce qui a rarement été une habitude en France, même pour les classes aisées, mais plutôt, suite à une dérive dans le temps observée au fil des ans, de modifier le contenu du repas appelé déjeuner qui avait fini par être pris vers midi. Cette dérive existe depuis le moyen-âge, époque à laquelle le dîner était le repas pris le matin et le souper se prenait en milieu d'après-midi.

Référence: [Les heures des repas en France avant le XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle](http://books.openedition.org/editionsmsh/8147?lang=fr)
Jean-Louis Flandrin

Note: Les noms *déjeuner* et *diner* appliqués aux repas pris respectivement le midi et le soir ont mis du temps à se généraliser en France et n'ont guère traversé les frontières car aussi bien en Belgique, en Suisse qu'au Canada, ces repas sont appelés *dîner* et *souper*.