# Comment comprendre le choix du mot « matinée » en tant que partie du jour dans l'après-midi ?

Tags: étymologie

Le TLFi  mentionne  ce terme, attesté en 1833.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/matin%C3%A9e)) B. − [P. oppos. à soirée, à propos d'un spectacle, d'une réunion] Après-midi. Quand il m'envoyait au studio des Ursulines voir − en matinée, avec ma mère − un film d'avant-garde ou à l'Atelier le dernier spectacle de Dullin, il me disait seulement: ,,Il ne faut pas manquer ça`` (Beauvoir, Mém. j. fille,1958, p.201).

L'étymologie telle que fournie par le TLFi n'est pas très révélatrice.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/matin%C3%A9e))3. 1833 «l'après-midi par opposition à la soirée» (Balzac, La Duchesse de Langeais, Comédie humaine, t. V, p.182 d'apr. Mat., p.61, n. 8);

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/matinee) lui reconnait une période d'origine similaire (attesté en 1848 selon cette source).

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/matin%C3%A9e)) matinée \ma.ti.ne\ féminin
> Représentation, spectacle qui a lieu l’après-midi, par opposition à la soirée.

Il serait intéressant de savoir comment ce mot, de la désignation d'une partie du jour qui est toujours avant midi, quelle que soit la variante, en est venu à être utilisé pour une partie du jour qui est dans l'après-midi.

Le littré ajoute un sens.

> ([Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/matin%C3%A9e)) De nos jours, dans les grandes villes surtout, on étend souvent la matinée jusqu'à l'heure du dîner, c'est-à-dire jusqu'à six ou sept heures du soir.

- Quel serait la cause du glissement vers « période du jour dans l'après-midi » ?
- Le sens nouveau attesté dans le Littré a-t-il pour origine le sens « partie du jour dans l'après-midi ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On trouve deux explications qui font chacune référence aux repas de la journée.

La première, de [Chambaron](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/member/chambaron/) sur [question-Orthographe](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/expression-une-matinale/), est la suivante :

> Les gens du spectacle et leurs spectateurs attitrés ont eu la réputation (surtout à Paris au XIXe siècle) d’être des lève-tard et de vivre décalés du reste de la population. Pour eux, la journée débutait à midi, et les spectacles d’après-midi étaient catalogués en « matinée », ce qui reste le cas de nos jours.  Le spectacle de « soirée » était la norme, et débouchait sur le « souper » important repas du beau monde,  que l’on prenait souvent à l’extérieur de chez soi, dans ces brasseries qui font encore l’animation des nuits de la capitale…

La deuxième est proposée par [Claude Duneton](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Duneton) dans un [article du Figaro](https://www.lefigaro.fr/livres/2010/03/25/03005-20100325ARTFIG00518-la-matinee-des-autres-.php) indique qu'un spectacle donné en « matinée » se déroulait avant le dîner (repas de milieu de journée sous l'ancien régime) et que le lent décalage de ce repas vers la soirée (d'abord spécifique à Paris puis étendu à la France entière mais pas en Suisse, en Belgique ou au Canada) à entraîné cette « matinée » dans son sillage.

Voir : [« Déjeuner à la fourchette » : précisions ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29547/d%C3%A9jeuner-%C3%A0-la-fourchette-pr%C3%A9cisions)

Comment: Pour la première partie de la question, exactement la sorte d'explication que je suspectait mais ne pouvait pas trouver.